# SQL display table in vertical

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

I am using C# and MySQL as (DBMS) I want to rotate my table. this is my query :

```
SELECT  p.gender,Count(CASE WHEN disease like '%Anemia%' THEN 1 END) AS 'Anemia'
       ,Count(CASE WHEN disease like '%Injuries%' THEN 1 END) AS 'Injuries'
FROM  phc_db.record r, phc_db.patient p
where r.malteser_id=p.malteser_id
group by p.gender
```

The result is :

```
Gender  Anemia  Injuries
------------------------
Female  1   0

Male    2   1
------------------------
```

And I want :

```
Disease  Male   Female
----------------------

Anemia   2      1

Injuries 1      0
----------------------
```

Any Idea? Any Suggestion? 
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Swap the aggregation:

```
SELECT
    (CASE WHEN disease LIKE '%Anemia%'   THEN 'Anemia'
          WHEN disease like '%Injuries%' THEN 'Injury'
     END) AS disease,
     SUM (p.gender = 'Female') AS females,
     SUM (p.gender = 'Male')   AS males
FROM phc_db.record r
INNER JOIN phc_db.patient p
     ON r.malteser_id = p.malteser_id
WHERE disease REGEXP 'Anemia|Injuries'
GROUP BY disease;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try pivoting on the disease instead of the gender.  In this case, the genders become columns.

```
SELECT
    disease,
    SUM(CASE WHEN p.gender = 'Male'   THEN 1 END) AS Male,
    SUM(CASE WHEN p.gender = 'Female' THEN 1 END) AS Female
FROM phc_db.record r
INNER JOIN phc_db.patient p
    ON r.malteser_id = p.malteser_id
GROUP BY disease
WHERE disease IN ('Anemia', 'Injuries')
```

Note that from your current output it appears that you may not need to use `LIKE` to match diseases.  In my query above, I check for the exact disease names of anemia and injuries.  If I assumed wrongly, then you can bring back `LIKE`.

Comment: Thanks a lot it appear a good look, but the problem is I want to use `like` because of this character `%`

Comment: Is it possible to use `Like` because of this character `%`, or do you have an idea to use `%` without `LIKE` .

Comment: @hogerqassim Look at Gordon's answer if you really need to use `LIKE` here.

Answer (score 0):

You can do in c# with following query which will get all the diseases

```
SELECT  p.gender, disease
FROM  phc_db.record r, phc_db.patient p
where r.malteser_id=p.malteser_id
```

The use following c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("Gender", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Disease", typeof(string));


            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Male", "Anemia"});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Female", "Anemia"});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Male", "Anemia"});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Female", "Anemia"});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Male", "Anemia"});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Male","Injuries" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Female", "Injuries" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Male", "Injuries" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Female", "Injuries" });

            string[] uniqueDieses = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(x => x.Field<string>("Disease")).Distinct().ToArray();

            DataTable pivot = new DataTable();
            pivot.Columns.Add("Disease", typeof(string));
            pivot.Columns.Add("Male", typeof(int));
            pivot.Columns.Add("Female", typeof(int));

            var groups = dt.AsEnumerable()
                .GroupBy(x => x.Field<string>("Disease")).Select(x => new
                {
                    disease = x.Key,
                    male = x.Where(y => y.Field<string>("Gender") == "Male").Count(),
                    female = x.Where(y => y.Field<string>("Gender") == "Female").Count()
                }).ToList();

            foreach (var group in groups)
            {
                pivot.Rows.Add(new object[] { group.disease, group.male, group.female });
            }
        }
    }
}
```